# Re-sign android applications?

Tags: android

My lecturer gave me a project on patching APK files. I wrote a sample application, using Apk_Manager 5.0 to patch the app. It's ok. But then I tried with an application downloaded from market.android.com, the re-signed application can't run on my Android Virtual Device. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

As a security feature Android will not let you install an updated version of an app that was not signed using the same keys. If this were allowed a malicious app with the same package name could gain access to private data stored by the original app. To install an app with the same package name but different signing keys you must first uninstall the original app, which will remove the app's private data.

Since you mentioned that you are attempting to modify other people's apps potentially without their knowledge or consent, please respect the copyrights of others. Many developers may consider this to be a breach of license.